# Silverlight: Flowing text around other objects

Tags: silverlight

I need to flow some text around some other objects. Basically something like this:

```
XXXX This is some
XXXX long text that
XXXX is being
wrapped around the
image shown with X's.
```

In my ideal world this would be an actual textbox, but simply showing text that is edited elsewhere would work.

Comment: Here is the similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381928/silverlight-text-around-an-image. The idea of one answer is based on the splitting the text into two text blocks. But It will not be so easy to make this text editable in the TextBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets easier in Silverlight 5.  You can use the RichTextBlock in conjunction with the RichTextBlockOverflow element.  You can link multiple RichTextBlockOverflow  within your XAML. Any content that doesn't fit in the RichTextBlock will overflow into the linked RichTextBlockOverflow element.

```
<RichTextBlock x:Name="MainTextBlock"
               OverflowContentTarget="{Binding ElementName=OverflowTextBox}"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Grid.Column='0'>
  <Paragraph>Content here..</Paragraph>
  <Paragraph>Content here..</Paragraph>
 </RichTextBlock>
 <RichTextBlockOverflow x:Name="OverflowTextBox"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                       Grid.Column='1' />
```

Comment: Alas Silverlight 5 is still far from production ready. Currently the printing is busted unless I use Comic Sans.